# How to do this effect pictured in illustrator or photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, illustrator-effects

How do I do this effect on text in Illustrator?
[image: Example]

Comment: Hi Sterre, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In Illustator:

[image]

1. Write your text and convert it to outlines
2. Draw a horizontal line on the division border
3. Select the line, goto Object > Path > Divide objects below, Ungroup, select the upper half and move it with the arrow key few ticks upwards to have an easily reversible safety gap
4. Select separately both halves, insert to them envelope distortion mesh which has 1 column+ 4 rows, select with the direct selection tools the top nodes of the lower half and shift them leftwards, adjust also bending handles to get the curvature. make the opposite mod to the bottom nodes of the top half
5. Select the upper half and move it back to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Crop the top part and move it to its seperate layer. Do the same with the bottom part.
Then using the liquify effect apply it as needed. Thats all